# Running (Average True Range) calculation in a column SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a dataset of price data and would like to get the calculation of the ongoing ATR (Average True Range) for all rows > 21.  Row 21 is the AVG([TR]) from Rows 2-21 and is equal to 353.7.

The calculation that needs to be continuous for the rest of that [ATR_20] column will need to be:

```
     ATR_20 (after row 21) = (([Previous ATR_20]*19)+[TR])/20
```

My dataset:

```
Date        Open    High    Low     Close   TotalVolume Prev_Close  TR_A  TR_B  TR_C   TR    ATR    

2017-02-01  5961    5961    5425    5498    22689       NULL        536   NULL  NULL   NULL  NULL 
2017-02-02  5697    5868    5615    5734    22210       5498        253   370   117    370   NULL
2017-02-03  5742    5811    5560    5725    15852       5734        251   77    174    251   NULL
2017-02-06  5675    5679    5545    5554    9777        5725        134   46    180    180   NULL
2017-02-07  5597    5613    5426    5481    12692       5554        187   59    128    187   NULL
2017-02-08  5459    5630    5450    5625    9134        5481        180   149   31     180   NULL
2017-02-09  5615    5738    5532    5668    10630       5625        206   113   93     206   NULL
2017-02-10  5651    5661    5488    5602    9709        5668        173    7    180    180   NULL
2017-02-13  5700    6195    5639    6161    26031       5602        556   593   37     593   NULL
2017-02-14  6197    6594    6073    6571    35969       6161        521   433   88     521   NULL
2017-02-15  6510    6650    6275    6492    22046       6571        375   79    296    375   NULL
2017-02-16  6505    6680    6325    6419    12515       6492        355   188   167    355   NULL
2017-02-17  6434    6670    6429    6658    14947       6419        241   251   10     251   NULL
2017-02-21  6800    6957    6603    6654    23838       6658        354   299   55     354   NULL
2017-02-22  6704    6738    6145    6222    25004       6654        593   84    509    593   NULL
2017-02-23  6398    6437    5901    6343    46677       6222        536   215   321    536   NULL
2017-02-24  5280    5589    5260    5404    51757       6343        329   754   1083   1083  NULL
2017-02-27  5437    5461    5260    5300    19831       5404        201   57    144    201   NULL
2017-02-28  5258    5410    5167    5195    15900       5300        243   110   133    243   NULL
2017-03-01  5251    5299    5052    5215    16958       5195        247   104   143    247   NULL
2017-03-02  5160    5231    5063    5130    17805       5215        168   16    152    168   353.7
2017-03-03  5141    5363    5088    5320    14516       5130        275   233   42     275   NULL
```

I got to this point by the following

```
WITH cte_ACIA ([RowNumber], [Date], [Open], [High], [Low], [Close], 
     [Prev_Close], [TotalVolume], [TR_A], [TR_B], [TR_C])
AS
(SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Date] ASC) RowNumber,
    [Date],
    [Open],
    [High],
    [Low],
    [Close],
    LAG([Close]) OVER(ORDER BY [Date]) AS Prev_Close,
    [TotalVolume],
    ROUND([High]-[Low], 5) AS TR_A,
    ABS(ROUND([High]-LAG([Close]) OVER(ORDER BY [Date]), 5))  AS TR_B,
    ABS(ROUND([Low]-LAG([Close]) OVER(ORDER BY [Date]), 5))  AS TR_C,
    FROM NASDAQ.ACIA_TEMP)

SELECT  [RowNumber], [Date], [Open], [High], [Low], [Close], [Prev_Close], 
        [TotalVolume], [TR_A], [TR_B], [TR_C], [TR],
        CASE
            WHEN RowNumber = 21 THEN AVG([TR]) OVER (ORDER BY [Date] ASC ROWS 19 PRECEDING)
        END AS ATR_20  
FROM 
    (
     SELECT [RowNumber],[Date],[Open],[High],[Low],[Close],
            IIF(RowNumber = 1, NULL, Prev_Close) Prev_Close,
            [TotalVolume],
            [TR_A],
            IIF(RowNumber > 1, [TR_B], NULL) TR_B,
            IIF(RowNumber > 1, [TR_C], NULL) TR_C,
            CASE
                WHEN TR_A > TR_B AND TR_A > TR_C THEN TR_A
                WHEN TR_B > TR_A AND TR_B > TR_C THEN TR_B
                ELSE TR_C
            END AS TR
     FROM cte_ACIA) sub
```

Please let me know if you have questions or I need to clarify anything.

Comment: The syntax will be different depending on your RDBMS, however, you've tagged 2 very different ones (I've removed these tags to avoid confusion). Please can you update you tags to only include the RDBMS you are using. Also, can you include what you've tried so far please? Thanks.

Comment: Tag properly!! MySQL <> SQL Server.  Which one is this???

Comment: Sorry first post.  I've added my code to my original post.  The issue I'm having is that if I try and do my calculation for RowNumber > 21 it will not continually calculate down the column for each row.  My guess would be that the previous ATR_20 is not in memory when the next row is trying to calculate.  Thanks for suggestions and help!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are just looking for a hint. Otherwise you would have posted your table definition.  We can't construct a query for you since we don't have the basic pieces.  However, here's the hint!  Use an aggregating window function with the OVER clause specifying ROWS PRECEDING.

See [SELECT - OVER Clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: I've added my query to get me to that table thus far.